# Python dictionary "copy value"

Tags: python, docutils

I was looking at the docutil source code (which is in python), when I saw this (redacted) :

```
def __init__(self, **attributes):
    for att, value in attributes.items():
        att = att.lower()
        if att in self.list_attributes:
            # mutable list; make a copy for this node
            self.attributes[att] = value[:]
        else:
            self.attributes[att] = value
```

The line I'm talking about is this one:

```
            self.attributes[att] = value[:]
```

What does the "[:]" do exactly ? The comment above it hint a copy of some kind but my google searchs were not that successful and I can't figure if it's a language feature or a trick/shortcut of some kind.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It makes a copy of the list (it's not a dictionary)

The notation is called "slicing". You can also specify where to start and end copying, if you don't specify anything - as in your code extract - it will copy from the first to the last element.

For instance, `mylist[1:]` will copy the entire list omitting the first element.

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/good-primer-for-python-slice-notation) for a comprehensive explanation.

Comment: Thank you, it answers my question perfectly. I'll mark it as an answer as soon as the site allows me too (in 8 minutes more or less)

Comment: Note that it is not a deep copy; it simply copies the references to each object and stores them in a new list.  While this should not be your copy method of choice for everything, it is useful if you want to iterate over and modify a list at the same time without screwing up your iteration.